# Inverted Scooped corners using CSS

Tags: html, css

I have CSS code

```css
#box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
  border-top-left-radius: 9999px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 9999px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

#box::before,
#box::after {
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

#box::before {
  border-right: 10px solid blue;
  border-top: 10px solid blue;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
  bottom: -20px;
}

#box::after {
  border-right: 10px solid blue;
  border-top: 10px solid transparent;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 10px solid blue;
  position: absolute;
  top: -20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="box">#box</div>
```

which gives some shape like

[image: box with inverted scooped corners]

shape I need is
[image]

I need curved line instead of hypotenuse in triangles at top-right (`#box::before`) and bottom-right (`#box::after`) as in image.

Is there any way to achieve using pure CSS ?

codesandbox [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-sun-33k72)

Thanks

Comment: Hei, see if this is what you want,

#box::before {
  ...
  border-bottom-right-radius: 75%;
}

#box::after {
  ...
  border-top-right-radius: 75%;

Comment: @theVoogie Nope! its giving some weird shape

Comment: Can you please add the image of shape which you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily achieve this by using svg background images like in this snippet. Here the curves may not the way you want but surely you can change the path in the svg to your needs.

```css
#box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
  border-top-left-radius: 9999px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 9999px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 30px;
}

#box::before,
#box::after {
  content: "";
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

#box::before {
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path fill="blue" d="M0 0 Q20 0 20 20 L20 0Z" /></svg>');
  bottom: -20px;
}

#box::after {
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path fill="blue" d="M0 20 Q20 20 20 0 L20 20Z" /></svg>');
  top: -20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="box"></div>
```

Answer (score 8):

You can create a concaved radius using the box-shadow property.

1. This technique creates a transparant square with overflow hidden.

   [image]
2. It then creates a transparant circle with a box shadow.

   [image]
3. We then adjust the position of the circle to only view 1 quarter of
       it.

   [image]

---

**SNIPPET**

```css
#box {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius: 9999px 0 0 9999px;
  margin: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

#top,
#bottom {
  position: absolute;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  right: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#top {
  top: -30px;
}

#bottom {
  bottom: -30px;
}

#top::before,
#bottom::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  height: 200%;
  width: 200%;
  border-radius: 100%;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px 100px blue;
  z-index: -1;
}

#top::before {
  top: -100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="box">
  <div id="top"></div>
  #box
  <div id="bottom"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for answer. Is it possible to do without extra elements ? Just using `::after` and `::before`

Comment: Unfortunately no. This technique needs two elements.The first to create the overflow boundary and the second to create the radius.

Answer (score 4):

Can you use negative space? You could have a container with the same background color as your shape, then round the corners surrounding elements to create the illusion.

```css
.container {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100%;
}

.negat {
  background-color: white;
  height: 100px;
}

.posit-bg {
  background-color: white;
}

.posit {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50px 0px 0px 50px;
}

.top {
  border-radius: 0px 0px 50px 0px;
}

.bot {
  border-radius: 0px 50px 0px 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="negat top"></div>
  <div class="posit-bg">
    <div class="posit"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="negat bot"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This has a white background and not a transparant one. If the blue tab is placed on top of another layer it will mask the underlying one. So it will not be fitting for every situation.

Answer (score 2):

```css
#box{
  width:200px;
  height:50px;
  background-color:blue;
  color:#ffffff;
  text-align:center;
  padding-top:30px;
  border-radius:9999px 0 0 9999px;
}
.sq{
  width:25px;
  height:25px;
  background-color:blue;
}
#sq1,#sq2,#sq11,#sq22{
  border-radius:-999px;
  margin-left:175px;
}
.sq1{
  background-color:#ffffff;
  height:25px;
  width:25px;
}
#sq11{
 border-bottom-right-radius:9999px;
  margin-bottom:-25px;
  position: relative;
  z-index:1;
}
#sq22{
 border-top-right-radius:9999px;
 margin-top:-25px;
 position: relative;
 z-index:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="sq1" id="sq11"></div>
<div class="sq" id="sq1"></div>
<div id="box">#box</div>
<div class="sq" id="sq2"></div>
<div class="sq1" id="sq22"></div>
```