# How can I achieve this complex shape using html css?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

[image: complex shape]

What is this kind of shape called? And I am not sure what is the best to handle this. Also, the width can be variable based on the length of the text within. I would prefer to avoid svg here because of other functionality associated to this and svg will pose limitations.

Comment: very complex CSS could possibly do it

Comment: Please show us what you were able to do it so far. It's hard to tell what parts you don't understand.

Comment: CSS is probably too complex for such a shape, use an SVG instead.

Comment: _"What is this kind of shape called?"_ - dunno, a "charcuterie board with handle" maybe ...? Perhaps not every single Rorschach Test looking arbitrary thing imaginable _has_ a dedicated name.

Comment: @Paulie_D i mean - yea sure its complex. but surely not _too complex for css_. The questions is about how to do it with css... But im with ya, using an SVG is surely a lot easier!

Comment: It's the inset curves that are the issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57799896/inverted-scooped-corners-using-css

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this, <s>but you're going to have a very difficult time getting the border colors to play nice. Honestly You'd probably end up having to duplicate the whole thing and scale down slightly + overlay it to get a decent border color on it.</s>

**Edit: Been thinking about this a bit more and decided to try and tackle the border issue and add some of the other features. The border actually wasn't that difficult.**

Definitely just use an SVG.

```css
.charcuterieContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;

  --main-color: #ecf;
  --border-color: #a8d;
}

.charcuterieHandle {
  background-color: var(--main-color);
  border-radius: 9999px;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  position: relative;
  border: 2px solid var(--border-color);
  border-right: none;
  transform: translate(2px, 0);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.charcuterieHandle::before,
.charcuterieHandle::after {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 60px;
  min-height: 60px;
  right: 0;
  background: radial-gradient(circle at center, transparent 28px, var(--border-color) 28px, var(--border-color) 30px, var(--main-color) 30px);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
}

.charcuterieHandle::before {
  top: 100%;
  clip-path: inset(0 0 50% 50%);
}

.charcuterieHandle::after {
  bottom: 100%;
  clip-path: inset(50% 0 0 50%);
}

.charcuterieBoard {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: var(--main-color);
  border-radius: 30px;
  border: 2px solid var(--border-color);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.charcuterieContent {
  background-color: #fffa;
  width: calc(100% - 40px);
  height: calc(100% - 40px);
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.inputContainer {
  background-color: white;
  border: 2px solid var(--border-color);
  min-width: 80px;
  min-height: 36px;
  border-radius: 9999px;
  margin: 10px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.inputText {
  border: none;
  margin: 0 8px;
}

.inputText:focus-within {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="charcuterieContainer">
  <div class="charcuterieHandle">
    <div class="inputContainer">
      <span class="inputText" contenteditable>Path 1</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="charcuterieBoard">
    <div class="charcuterieContent"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks pretty good on Chrome 122.0.6261.112, but the inner curves of the handle are slightly jagged. This echoes my experience trying to do something similar with only CSS: I could make it work, but I couldn't get consistently smooth curves and had to switch to an SVG (as you recommend).

Comment: @TimM. Yeah I noticed that as well. I'm not sure there's really anything that could be done about that, but to be honest I'm not a CSS master or anything. I just know enough to get what I need done. I'm sure there are better/more efficient ways to achieve what I got done here.